# Node WebKit: File Dialog select directory path

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I am trying to add a folder selector to my node webkit app. Looking at the docs I can just use:

```
<input type="file" nwdirectory />
```

But these still seems to return the number of files, which it is not supposed to do.

here is the test code,

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileDialog" nwdirectory />
    <script>
      function chooseFile(name) {
        var chooser = $(name);
        chooser.change(function(evt) {
          console.log($(this).val());
        });
        chooser.trigger('click');  
      }
      chooseFile('#fileDialog');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get just the folder path as I will then use this with the fs module

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This looks like a regression issue in v0.12.0 Alpha as it appears to work fine in v0.11.5.

Hope this is helpful for you.